# How can there only be continuum many measurable functions if it is consistent with ZF that all real functions are measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is well known that proving the existence of measurable sets or functions requires the axiom of choice, which means that it is consistent with ZF that all functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  are measurable. However, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-many-borel-measurable-functions-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-are-there) it is argued that there are only continuum many measurable functions, an apparent contradiction as the set of all functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has a cardinality greater than the continuum.

Clearly there's some use of axiom of choice somewhere here that resolves the apparent contradiction, but I really don't see it. Where is AoC used and what's going on?

Comment: Point of order: ZF + "all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are Lebesgue measurable" is equiconsistent with ZF + "an inaccessible cardinal exists". So it is strictly stronger than ZF in terms of consistency strength.

Comment: You have to distinguish between different types of measurability: *Borel-measurability* is rather narrow, and $\mathsf{ZF}$ does in fact prove that there are non-Borel-measurable functions (as long as the right notion of "Borel" is used here - see [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638461/there-is-a-sigma1-1-universal-set-and-this-is-not-borel-where-did-we-use-th/3638572#3638572)).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Do you want to make an answer from that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is a $\Sigma^1_1$ universal set and this is not Borel. Where did we use the axiom of choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638461/there-is-a-sigma1-1-universal-set-and-this-is-not-borel-where-did-we-use-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Belatedly turning my comment into an answer, per the OP's request:*

There are different types of measurability. While it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (relative to large cardinals) that every function is measurable in the Lebesgue sense, the result you cite is about *Borel* measurability. Indeed, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that there are non-Borel-measurable functions.

... **As long as** we define "Borel" in the right way. There are two obvious notions of Borel-ness: "element of the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets" and "having an explicit Borel code." $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that most sets of reals are not Borel in the latter sense, but is consistent with all sets being Borel in the former sense. See [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638461/there-is-a-sigma1-1-universal-set-and-this-is-not-borel-where-did-we-use-th/3638572#3638572) (and note that the terminology used there is nonstandard).